# Trouble with sizing ul ul li

Tags: html, css, html-lists, stylesheet

Ok. So I need to do something like this:
[image: the needed way]
I do it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="bla.png"></li>
    <li><img src="bla2.png></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>line 1</li>
            <li>line 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But whatever i Try i get this:

[image: wrong1]

I tried to make this :

```
ul ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

But i only got this:
[image]

I tried to change line-height, but it didn't work!

Please, help me!!!

Thanks, in advance

Comment: FIrst of all, you've markup error `<li><img src="bla2.png></li>`

Comment: why not use td and tr to aligned then and just do a ul inside that instead of the initial ul... everytime i try to add style to a dom element inside a dom element of the same dom element i never get the desired results.

Comment: Did you reset all your `margin`s and `padding`s to `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NKXPx/)

```
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
ul li ul > li{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: you don't need the > between the last ul and li: ul li ul li { just works as well

Comment: `ul li ul li` will affect further child elements(ul li ul li ul li) as well. That's why I didnt used it.

Comment: Hey Sonu, have you considered using class names to solve this?